# PHP: How to split a number to multiple strings

Tags: php, string, function, datetime, split

I want to split a long number which i got into multiple strings in PHP. 
I got this:

```
<?php
$this = 020420151230;
?>
```

I want to get this result:

```
//output:
    $this['day'] = 02;
    $this['month'] = 04;
    $this['year'] = 2015;
    $this['hour'] = 12;
    $this['minute'] = 30;
```

Can you please help and advice which function should i use for this?

Comment: What did you try? Sounds easy doesn't it ?

Comment: http://php.net/substr

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
 $datetime = "020420151230"; 
 $dd = substr($datetime,0,2);
 $mm = substr($datetime,2,2);
 $yyyy = substr($datetime,4,4);
 $hh = substr($datetime,8,2);
 $MM = substr($datetime,10,2);

 echo $this['day'] = $dd;     //02
 echo $this['month'] = $mm;   //04
 echo $this['year'] = $yyyy;  //2015
 echo $this['hour'] = $hh;    //12
 echo $this['minute'] = $MM;  //30
?>
```

Comment: @lowmatic : let me know if it is useful for you :)

Answer (score 7):

Forget splitting and extracting parts of it, if the format always remains same then use the neat date time functions that are already there for that purpose :)

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYHi', '020420151230');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H i');     
?>
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/307956)**

Now please don't ask how can you extract individual values, because you easily can :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as array that try this,

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYHi', '020420151230');
$array = array('day'=>$date->format('d'),'month'=>$date->format('m'),'year'=>$date->format('Y'),'hour'=>$date->format('H'),'minute'=>$date->format('i')); 

print_r($array);
?>
```

`020420151230` it self a datetime format  so you can use php function directly

[Code](https://eval.in/307961)

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [day] => 02
    [month] => 04
    [year] => 2015
    [hour] => 12
    [minute] => 30
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match` function.

```
$date = '020420151230';
preg_match('~^(?<day>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<year>\d{4})(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})$~', $date, $match);
print_r($match);
```